# Redirect all URLs to secured URLs without www in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, http, redirect, https

I am using the code below to redirect all my traffic to https version without www i.e. for one my application hosted on a subdomain. It should work for the following cases:

- http://subdomain.domain.com
- http://www.subdomain.domain.com
- https://www.subdomain.domain.com
- www.subdomain.domain.com

All the above should redirect to **https://subdomain.domain.com**.

I am trying out this on my Node.js application.

```
app.use('*', function(req, res, next) {

    // https
    if (req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] == "https") {

        // https with www
        if (req.headers.host.match(/^www/) !== null) {
            res.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.headers.host.replace(/^www\./, '') + req.url);
        }

        // https without www
        else {
            next();
        }
    }

    // http
    else {

        // http with www
        if (req.headers.host.match(/^www/) !== null) {
            res.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.headers.host.replace(/^www\./, '') + req.url);
        }

        // http without www
        else {
            res.redirect("https://subdomain.domain.com" + req.url);
        }
    }
});
```

I am not able to get the redirection working. For the fourth URL i.e. www.subdomain.domain.com, I have updated my DNS as well.

Comment: What's the 4th URL (`www.subdomain.domain.com`) mean? All URLs have protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Below Code Snippet Check if URL is not secure it redirects to https with replacing www from url.

```
app.use('*',function(req, res, next){
 if (!req.secure) {
   res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host.replace(/\/\/www\./, '') + req.url);
 }
 next();
})
```